# Python decorator call function multiple times

Tags: python, python-decorators

Is there any way to call a function multiple times with a decorator?

Here is my code:

```
def call_func(**case):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **case)
        return wrapped_function
    return decorator

@call_func(p=1, o=2)
@call_func(p=3, o=4)
@call_func(p=5, o=6)
def some_func(p, o):
    print(p, o)

some_func()
```

And the output is:

```
(5, 6)
```

But I want:

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
```

Is this possible? And, is this Pythonic?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve actually.  This sounds like a good use case for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)  As it is, each time you use that decorator it's just nesting the original function in a deeper and deeper layer of wrapper functions.  It's not going to call the original function more than once.

Answer (score 3):

```
import functools
def call_func(cache={}, **case):
    def decorator(func):
        funcname = func.__name__
        if funcname not in cache:
            # save the original function
            cache[funcname] = func
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped_function(**kwargs):
            if cache[funcname] != func:
                cache[funcname](**case)
            func(**case)
        return wrapped_function
    return decorator

@call_func(p=1, o=2)
@call_func(p=3, o=4)
@call_func(p=5, o=6)
def some_func(p, o):
    print(p, o)

some_func()
```

yields

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
```

---

Your `call_func` decorator is close to creating the desired chain of function calls.
Consider that:

```
def call_func(**case):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped_function(**kwargs):
            print(case)
            func(**case)
        return wrapped_function
    return decorator

@call_func(p=1, o=2)
@call_func(p=3, o=4)
@call_func(p=5, o=6)
def some_func(p, o):
    print(p, o)

some_func()
```

yields

```
{'p': 1, 'o': 2}
{'p': 3, 'o': 4}
{'p': 5, 'o': 6}
(5, 6)
```

So the `wrapped_functions` are clearly being called in the right order, and with the desired values for `case`. The only problem is that we want to call the **original function `some_func`** at each stage.

Somehow we need to give each `wrapped_function` access to the original `some_func`.

We can do that by giving `call_func` a cache which records the first time it sees a function of a certain name. This is the purpose of

```
def call_func(cache={}, **case):
    def decorator(func):
        funcname = func.__name__
        if funcname not in cache:
            # save the original function
            cache[funcname] = func
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do it with single decorators. The tricky part is that you can't have multiples of the same key in a dict. The first way uses a list of dicts. The second way uses a dict of tuples, so we can take advantage of Python's machinery for passing named arguments to build the dict from the supplied args.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Decorator demo

    Decorate a function so it can be called multiple times 
    with different args specified in the decorator.

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/28767826/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.02.28
'''

from __future__ import print_function

def multicall0(argdicts):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for d in argdicts:
                func(**d)
        return wrapped_function
    return decorator

dlist = [
    {'p':1, 'o':2}, 
    {'p':3, 'o':4}, 
    {'p':5, 'o':6},
]

@multicall0(dlist)
def some_func(p, o):
    print(p, o)

some_func()

# ------------------------------------

def multicall1(**kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        dlist = [[(k, v) for v in kwargs[k]] for k in kwargs.keys()]
        argdicts = [dict(item) for item in zip(*dlist)]
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for d in argdicts:
                func(**d)
        return wrapped_function
    return decorator

@multicall1(p=(10, 30, 50, 70), o=(20, 40, 60, 80))
def another_func(p, o):
    print(p, o)

another_func()
```

**output**

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
10 20
30 40
50 60
70 80
```

Is it Pythonic? Maybe not. :)